# Partial row by row matching of two vectors

Tags: r

I would to like to indicate if `x` is contained in `y`, preferably without using a loop. I tried the following but it produces an error.

```
df$flag <- ifelse(grep(df$x, df$y), 1, 0)
```

Here is the example:

```
df <- data.frame(id=seq(1,3,1),x=c("abc","efd","xyz"), y=(c("abc,efd","hig,mno","abc,xyz")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use the *stringi* function `stri_detect_fixed()`.  It is vectorized over both its string and pattern arguments, is very fast, and will not be limited by the maximum number of regex characters that may occur by pasting together a large number of rows (I found this out by pasting 30k rows, which returns an *invalid regular expression* error in `grepl()`).

```
df$flag <- as.integer(stringi::stri_detect_fixed(df$y, df$x))
df
#   id   x       y flag
# 1  1 abc abc,efd    1
# 2  2 efd hig,mno    0
# 3  3 xyz abc,xyz    1
```

Another alternative, albeit a loop, is `mapply()`

```
df$flag <- as.integer(mapply(grepl, df$x, df$y))
```

Comment: Thanks! both options are functional and run quite fast. I ended using the mapply due to the NA handling.

Answer (score 1):

We `paste` the 'x' column together, use that as `pattern` to find the elements that matches the pattern in 'y' column.  The `grepl` returns a logical vector which can be coerced to binary by wrapping with `+`.

```
df$flag <- +(grepl(paste0(df$x, collapse='|'), df$y))
df
#  id   x       y flag
#1  1 abc abc,efd    1
#2  2 efd hig,mno    0
#3  3 xyz abc,xyz    1
```

Just to be safe, we can also use the word boundary so that it will not match any patterns within a word

```
 +(grepl(paste0('\\b(', paste0(df$x, collapse='|'), ')\\b'), df$y))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know your patterns are always separated by a comma you don't need a regular expression.

```
df$flag <-  as.integer(apply(df, 1, function(r) { r[2] %in% strsplit(r[3], ",", fixed=T)[[1]] }))
```